# Python: Is it possible to delete values in a range of excel cells without iterating cell by cell?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, range

I'm writing into a spreadsheet with existing data. Before writing in data I need to delete the data in a specific range of cells. This has been particularly tricky to achieve. I've unsucessfully tried solutions in the following links. If you have experience with this, would appreciate the guidance.

code to select worksheet:

```
ws = 'tmp'
for s in range(len(shts)):
    if wb.sheetnames[s] == ws:
        break
wb.active = s
sht = wb.active
```

1. [Setting an Excel Range with an Array using Python and comtypes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150017/setting-an-excel-range-with-an-array-using-python-and-comtypes#2150140)

```
cell_range = eval('self.sht.Range(\self.sht.Cells%s, self.sht.Cells%s)' % \
                ("A11", "G1000"))
```

can't get to the deleting data code as the range selection itself provides an error:

```
  File "C:\Users\shefali\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3418, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-49-99fdfabfb7fa>", line 2, in <module>
    ("A11", "G1000"))
  File "<string>", line 1
    self.sht.Range(\self.sht.CellsA11, self.sht.CellsG1000)
                                                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

another solution from the same link didn't work either:

```
sht.Range("A11", "G1000").Value = ''
```

2. [delete content of particular Excel cells python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48305125/delete-content-of-particular-excel-cells-python)

```
stcell = 'A11'
# delete old data in worksheet
cols = len(dfPR.columns) # gets the number of columns to delete the data for.
sht.range(stcell, 'G1000').value=None
```

3. https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range.html: this link discusses how to refer to a range, but from what I read it does not allow one to set the value of the cells in this range.

VBA has a straightforward command. Surely there must be an equivalent to this:

```
Worksheets("tmp").Range("A11:G1000").Clear
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Celius Stingher's idea led me to the following hack. It's not elegant but works. So I'll wait for a few days to get a better answer before accepting this one:

```
ws = 'tmp'

# get start row and start col
stcell = 'A11'
cell= coordinate_to_tuple(stcell) # (function taken from here: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/utils/cell.html)
strow = cell[0]-1
stcol = cell[1]-1

# update sheet in writer
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets) #the writer was created originally in the code

# check worksheet exists and make active
for s in range(len(shts)):
    if wb.sheetnames[s] == ws:
        break
wb.active = s
sht = wb.active

# delete old data in worksheet
cols = len(dfPR.columns)  # get number of columns to overwrite from dataframe with the new data.
df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros([1000, cols])*np.nan) # creates a dummy df with nans
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = ws, startrow = strow, startcol=stcol, index = False, header=False) # deletes data in first n cols.

# write new data
dfPR.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = ws, startrow = strow, startcol=stcol, index = False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using pandas, if it you want to delete the content inside a cell you could fill it with np.nan. I would do as follows:

```
df = pd.read_excel('location_to_file.xlsx') #Here we read the excel
df.iloc[11:1001,:8] = np.nan #Here we are selecting from the first column upto the seventh (G) and from the 11th row up to the 1000 and making the values null.
df.to_excel('location_of_new_file.xlsx') #Here we are saving the excel with the modifications we made.
```

Comment: thanks. This will not work as I'm deleting only some data in a file. The rest of the columns have formulas that refer to the new data I'm pasting in. So I cannot create a new file.

Comment: Your idea leads me to a hack. I can create a df with nans with the rows and columns I want and then paste that data into the cells. Will try.

Comment: Another option which I also enjoy is replacing the character `=` in the beginning of the formulas with `#` therefore it is text, you then make the changes in python and save it back and then replace the `#` back to `=` so your formulas work as usual. You don't need to create a new file, you can overwrite it.

Comment: that's a cool hack. I'm not bringing in the formulas into my dataframe. So it won't work in this case but retaining formula's has always been painful in the past. Will try this out.

Comment: Yeah, that's how I manage both in excel and before importing data to pandas